# Loading CSV as a GIS layer into QGIS 3.4 not possible with certain coordinate reference systems

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

I tried multiple times to load a CSV (CRS: EPSG 4647) into QGIS 3.4.
While it works without problems in QGIS 2.x versions, there was no success loading it into QGIS 3.4 ('QGIS Madeira').

Do you have any suggestions of what I should pay attention to?

Comment: I know that the CSV dialogue is slightly different so you have to expand the geometry definition option. Have you noticed this? If so, then what is happening when you try to add it?

Comment: Hey AWGIS, thanks for your reply. Yes, I was aware of this.

Comment: Okay, could you give a little more detail as to the steps you take and at what stage it doesn't work please?

Comment: Do you use point or comma as decimal separator for coordinates? In QGIS3 there is now a checkbox for comma as separator.

Comment: What does no success mean. You didnt get new layer after import or just table without geometry? If you can import table you can try using table to points layer tool. If you post sample of your data and exact steps you used to import csv maybe someone can help..